# ¿Como pasar valores de una relación a vista show?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tablas que tiene relación muchos a muchos (`people` ,`properties`, su tabla pivote `people_properties`), en sus respectivos modelos existe el método que posee hasMAny y belongsToMany (respectivamente).

En mi archivo web de rutas, para cada una de mis tablas estoy usando `Route::resource`, en mi ruta show de `people` necesito ver los datos de la person seleccionada y las de los properties con los que tenga relación, pero no se como hacer esto, ya que el metodo Show recibe `Person $person`

Answer (score 0):

Person es un Model? En caso que sea, debe tener una relacion belongsTo con People. En este caso, cuando se crea ésta relación, en la view podes acceder a las columnas de People a través del nombre del método que colocaste en el Model de Person.

Por ejemplo: {{ $person->methodName->desiredProperty }}

Comment: La relacion es muchos a muchos por lo tanto no se usa belongsTo

Comment: Como habia explicado, es una relacion muchos a muchos, por lo que es un belongsTomany, pero tienes razon en que puedo usarlo directamente desde blade...Pero y si necesito hacerlo en vue? No me funciona igual

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

Resulta que los elementos del objetos que puedes manejar desde vue son dependientes de los que uses en laravel, es decir, en mi caso propuesto en la pregunta requería todos los `properties` que tuvieran relación con `person`, pero estos los llamaba directamente en vue (`person.people`) sin llamarlos antes en laravel (`$person->people`), la solución fue llamarlos primero desde laravel (ya sea invocando el metodo `$person->people` en el metodo show del controlador, o en una `section php` de blade), para que estos datos fueran incluidos en el array que es pasado a vue.

Espero que a alguien mas le sea de ayuda